# Kernel specific compile

Tags: unix, compilation, kernel, xubuntu

I need help to generate a "specific hardware" .config for my kernel.

Yesterday evening i've installed on an old Asus EEE-Pc 900HD the latest version of Xubuntu 14.10, and I'm trying to optimize this installation. I'd like to know how to do the "make menuconfig" for compiling ONLY the modules and the components that my hardware requires, and not all the rest. I'd also like to add the Grsecurity patch for this version.

Goal of this project could be a very minimal and optimized kernel for this old but gold machine.

Can someone help me, please?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really care about this... There is something called Ktest that will figure this out for you. But it's through automated trial and error.

See: http://elinux.org/Ktest

Take a look at the `make_min_config` option.